# Is there some tax reporting application?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am filing tax report in US using [Federal 1040 form](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040.pdf). I was wondering if there is some software for tax report, with similar purpose as [turbotax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TurboTax)? Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be having a major issue with that Federal 1040 Form, my friend.

This time I can't give you a suggestion for this software-recommendation issue.

Turbotax (free edition), somehow, seems to be running perfectly in google-chrome (as it seems to be a browser based application). I just found a couple of warnings when I tried to register using google-chrome and they were about the suggestion of using a stable (non-beta) version of some browsers which includes Google-Chrome, Firefox and others.

Take a look at this screenshots and give it a try. Or please inform, if you are trying to run a windows application maybe you can find useful giving a try to install it through "wine".

Good luck!

### Turbotax in chromium-browser:

[image]

[image]

### Additional Screenshots here:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `google-chrome` or `chromium-browser`? `google-chrome` is not free ;)

Comment: The webpage screenshots were taken inside of google-chrome, the browser screenshots are chromium-browser. :)

Answer (score 1):

**[OpenTaxSolver](http://opentaxsolver.sourceforge.net/)** ([Download Link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opentaxsolver/files/OTS_2010/v8.05/OpenTaxSolver2010_8.05.tgz/download))

[image]

> OpenTaxSolver (OTS) is a free program for calculating Tax Form entries and tax-owed or refund-due, such as Federal or State personal income taxes.
>
> The updated version of OTS for the 2010 tax year has been posted. It contains the updated US 1040 with Schedules A, B, C, D, L, and -just added- M. It also contains the State Tax form updates for CA, VA, OH, NC, NJ, PA, NY, and MA. Some significant improvements were made to the GUI this year - namely, an automatic results viewer.

Instructions for running it

- After Downloading the tar file extract it and then mark the file Run_taxsolve_GUI_Unix.sh as executable (Heres how to do that) then double click and run it.